# Comparing list with a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list `string_array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']` and a list of lists 
`multi_list = [['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['4', '5'], ['5', '6']]`

The first element of each sub-list in `multi_list` will have an associated entry in `string_array`.

(Sublists will not have duplicate elements)

How do I map these associated elements into a dictionary like:

```
{
'1': ['2'],
'2': ['3', '4'],
'3': [],
'4': ['5'],
'5': ['6'],
'6': []
}
```

Comment: First create a dictionary containing empty lists for each element in the first list. Then loop through the second llist, appending the second item to the appropriate element of the dictionary.

Comment: Can there ever be a value in the second list that does not have a starting value which matches a value the first list?

Comment: What do you do if there are duplicates in the output?

Comment: @flakes The first value in the second list (list of lists) will always have a matching value in the first list. There will not be any duplicates in the output.

Comment: What’s the problem? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @AMC yes I have in fact and couldn't find related. I'm quite new to python.

Comment: @user12091650 Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: @AMC I was trying to directly compare the first element of each sublist with its corresponding element in the flat list. And if there was a match, add the second element to a new list. I did not figure out that I would have to create a dictionary first.

Comment: @user12091650 _I did not figure out that I would have to create a dictionary first._ I’m confused, doesn’t your question mention a dictionary?

Comment: Do you actually need those keys with empty lists?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wouldn't actually be using keys with empty lists, but would it not be good to maintain one since its easy to keep track of which value in the flat list does not have an associated value in the nested list?

Comment: _but would it not be good to maintain...._ I think you’re the only one who can really answer that.

Comment: @AMC _I think you’re the only one who can really answer that._ I think you should go through the "expected output" section which is just above the tags.

Comment: @user12091650 I’m confused, how is that related to what I wrote? You asked whether it would _be good to maintain one since it’s easy to keep track of which value in the flat list does not have an associated value in the nested list_. My point was that there is no universal answer to that, it depends on the specifics of the situation.

Comment: @AMC Of course it depends on the situation; I just wanted to know if its typically (in most use cases) considered good or not.

Comment: @AMC I'm actually confused to what your contribution is to this post. Barmar has suggested something which is implemented in the answers, Flakes has given a good hint about how my approach should have been, and Juanpa has suggested an improved solution to my accepted answer. I don't get what you're trying to do. You don't like the question, downvote it and carry on. And stop wasting my time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
flat = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
nested = [['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['4', '5'], ['5', '6']]

result = {key: [] for key in flat}

for key in result:
    result[key] = [nest[1] for nest in nested if key == nest[0]]


#{'1': ['2'], '2': ['3', '4'], '3': [], '4': ['5'], '5': ['6'], '6': []}
```

Using your flat list elements as keys, you can generate a dictionary and use empty lists are the values. Empty strings or `None` would also work if using list comprehension to generate the values later.

Then just iterate over the keys in the dictionary and your nested list to append the results to the appropriate keys.

Furthermore;

You can reduce the above down to a single line outputting the same result.

```
result = {key: [nest[1] for nest in nested if key == nest[0]] for key in flat}
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['2'], '2': ['3', '4'], '3': [], '4': ['5'], '5': ['6'], '6': []}
```

**EDIT:**

After assessing Juanpa's comment and testing the efficiency of the above code, it is clear there is much better ways to run this when encountering large data sets.

Comment for reference:

> This solution is O(N*M) where N and M are the sizes of flat and nested. You can do this in O(MAX(N, M)). Basically, loop over nested instead of result, and do for a,b in nested: result[a].append(b)

Running the above code, 1000 times, with 1000 elements in the flat list and 1000 nested lists in nested.. the run time is;

```
print(t.timeit(1000))
39.37227249999978
```

However running it with the below code boasts a much more efficient run time.

```
print(j.timeit(1000))
0.17638869999973394
```

Code:

```
result = {key: [] for key in flat}
for a, b in nested:
    if a in result:
        result[a].append(b)
```

Comment: How would you suggest tackling this with a larger dataset @juanpa.arrivillaga?

Comment: This solution is O(N*M) where N and M are the sizes of flat and nested. You can do this in O(MAX(N, M)). Basically, loop over nested instead of result, and do `for a,b in nested: result[a].append(b)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga After running over larger data sets it is clearly evident with the differences in efficiency. I have added the more efficient method and run times to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few concepts that will help you, but I'm not going to give you the complete solution. You should do so on your own to sink in the concepts.

To make an empty dictionary of lists

```
{
    '1': [],
    '2': [],
    '3': [],
    '4': [],
    '5': [],
    '6': [],
}
```

you can use a for loop:

```
list_one = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

my_dict = {}
for value in list_one:
    my_dict[value] = []
```

You could also get fancy and use a dictionary comprehension:

```
my_dict = {value: [] for value in list_one}
```

Now you'll need to loop over the second list and `append` to the current list. e.g. to append to a list you can do so in a few ways:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
c = 5

# add a list to a list
a += b
# now a = [1,2,3,4]

# add a list to a list
b.append(c)
# now b = [3,4,5]
```

To chop up lists you can use slice notation:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a[:2]
c = a[2:]
# now b = [1,2], and c = [3,4]
```

And to access an item in a dictionary, you can do so like this:

```
a = { '1': [1,2,3] }
a['1'] += [4,5,6]
# now a = { '1': [1,2,3,4,5,6] }
```

Comment: +1 It's always a good thing to provide an opportunity to OP to solve the problem by himself especially if he/she didn't provide any attempts.