# How to compare array of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

I have 2 lists like the following:

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,0]]
```

I want to return true if all the sublists in b are present in a and vice versa.
That means a should be equal to b but indexes of the sublists can be different.
eg:

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]
```

Above a and b are equal and comparison should return true. Also, the sublists will only contain a combination of 1s or 0s. How do I compare them?
I tried converting them to sets : set(a) but this is throwing an error.
Apart from that, when I tried the following code in a while loop, it gave an error

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]

def sublists_equal(a, b):
    return all(l for l in b if l in a)

print(sublists_equal(a, b))
```

The error was:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried printing both the arrays to see what the problem was, they are printing like follows:

```
[[0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]
[array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: You can convert each item to *tuple* and then compare *sets*: `set(map(tuple, a)) == set(map(tuple, b))`. If you want to use `all()` with generator: `all(i in b for i in a)`.

Comment: The second try seems to use numpy somewhere but only incompletely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing list with a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386357/comparing-list-with-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: In case if you're wondering why I've firstly recommended way which seems to be more complicated - [here is the test](https://repl.it/repls/RectangularDarkseagreenToolbox). *Spoiler: method with sets more then 10 times faster.*

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]
c=[[1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]

def check(a,b):
    status = True
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            status = False
            break
    return(status)
    
print(check(a,b))
print(check(a,c))
```

Comment: You can return immediately, no need to use temporary value